# Seleccionar ciertas columnas con query de excel C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente query para seleccionar un documento de excel,

```
Select * From [Sheet1$]
```

Pero este excel tiene muchas columnas, y yo solo necesito las columnas A,C,E,G,Z,AA.

Intenté hacer lo siguiente, pero no funcionó

```
Select * From [Sheet1$A1:A,C1:C,E1:E,G1:G,Z1:Z,AA1:A]
```

Si me pudieran ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Las columnas que necesitas no tienen nombre?

Comment: si tiene, pero al colocarle el nombre me aparece error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenemos dos situaciones:

> **1. Las columnas no tienen nombre.**

En este caso tenemos que especificarlo en la propiedad HDR `HDR = NO`

```
if (Path.GetExtension(pathArchivo).ToUpper() == ".XLSX")
{
         cb.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
         cb.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;");
}
```

Y nos referimos a las columnas como F1, F2, Fn, etc. según las que necesitemos, por ejemplo, si solo necesitamos las columnas A (F1) y C (F3):

```
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder cb = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
cb.DataSource = pathArchivo;

if (Path.GetExtension(pathArchivo).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
{
     cb.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
     cb.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;");
}
else if (Path.GetExtension(pathArchivo).ToUpper() == ".XLSX")
{
     cb.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
     cb.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;");
}

OleDbConnection conexionOleDb = new OleDbConnection(cb.ConnectionString);
conexionOleDb.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = conexionOleDb.CreateCommand();



cmd.CommandText = "SELECT F1,"                               
                   + "F3 "
                   + "FROM [Sheet1$]";
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

> **2. Las columnas si tienen nombre**

Colocamos la propiedad `HDR = YES` y especificamos el nombre de nuestras columnas, por ejemplo, la columna A se llama NOMBRE y la columna C se llama APELLIDO:

```
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder cb = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
    cb.DataSource = pathArchivo;

    if (Path.GetExtension(pathArchivo).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
    {
         cb.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
         cb.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;");
    }
    else if (Path.GetExtension(pathArchivo).ToUpper() == ".XLSX")
    {
         cb.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
         cb.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;");
    }

    OleDbConnection conexionOleDb = new OleDbConnection(cb.ConnectionString);
    conexionOleDb.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = conexionOleDb.CreateCommand();



    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOMBRE,"                               
                       + "APELLIDO "
                       + "FROM [Sheet1$]";
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió la situación  1 (pensaba que si tenían nombre las columnas)

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro las librerías de http://spreadsheetlight.com hay mucha documentación, tal vez podría encontrar algo.